# How to Change the Mouse Cursor / Pointer when Google Maps API v3 Info Window is Loading

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Recently on a project I was displaying an [Info Window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) on the click of a map marker where the content was loaded with an XHR request.  There was a noticeable delay from the time of the click event to when the AJAX callback triggered the opening of the Info Window and I wanted to change the mouse cursor to a 'wait' icon so the user knew their click had triggered something.

I first tried setting a cursor style on `body, html` but found the styles used by the map superseded this.

**So, how to set a wait cursor regardless of the mouse pointer being positioned over the marker, map, or elsewhere on the page?**

This is the first time I've posted a question I have an answer ready for.  I found some posts talking about setting either a map cursor or a marker cursor buy nothing concisely explaining how to accomplish what I am asking here.  Hope this saves someone a little time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the following code to accomplish this:

```
/**
* Event handler for marker click event
*/
function markerClickHandler(marker, event) {

    $('html, body').css("cursor", "wait");
    auctionMap.setOptions({draggableCursor: 'wait'});
    marker.setCursor('wait');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get-marker-info/' + marker.some_id,
        dataType: 'html',
    }).done(function(response) {
        infoWindow.setContent(response);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('An unknown error occurred.');
    }).always(function() {
        $('html, body').css("cursor", "auto");
        auctionMap.setOptions({draggableCursor: null});
        marker.setCursor(null);
    });
}
```

This gets a wait cursor to display when the mouse is **anywhere on the page, in or out of the map, and while over the marker**.

The `draggableCursor` by default uses an image of an open hand (http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur), not a standard [CSS cursor property value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).
This is why we use `null` when reverting the cursor after the call is completed, rather than say using the cursor `auto`.

It works well enough though is a little wonky in its interactions with mouse movement to trigger the transition.  Curious if anyone could improve the code in that regard.

See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/0ere5tju/